# С# консольное приложение

Tags: c#, консоль

Всем привет !

Есть консольное приложение (**очень примитивное**).
Есть у меня `Console.ReadKey()` при помощи которого я могу считать нажатую клавишу что бы приложение закрылось.

```
do {
 
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.A);
```

*К примеру тут закроется при нажатии А*

**Вопрос:** *как мне сделать так, что бы приложение не закрывалось при нажатии ЛЮБОЙ клавиши, а только когда нажимаю на крестик*

В принципе пробовал сделать `while(true){}` но это **очень глупо** :)

Спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну объедините свои два способа:

```
while (true) { Console.ReadKey(); }
```

`Console.ReadKey();` не даст грузить процессор, а `while (true)` не даст приложению закрыться.

Более правильное решение остановить текущий поток "навсегда":

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: Меня очень смущает то, что while(true) будет постоянно на фоне работать. Это нормально ?

Comment: `Console.ReadKey();` не даст ему постоянно работать, а только при нажатии клавиш, сейчас дополню ответ более правильным способом

Comment: Объеденил свои два варианта и сделал так, как у Вас в первом варианте. Спасибо большое и хорошего Вам дня :)