# Нажатие клавиш в консоли C#

Tags: c#, консоль, клавиатура

У меня вопрос. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа реагировала на нажатие клавиши, но когда пользователь не нажимал клавишу, программа продолжала работать. Когда я использую функцию

```
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Программа не продолжает работать, пока я не нажму клавишу. Как это изменить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755490/%d0%a1-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5?rq=1

Comment: tomato-magnet-regulato, спасибо, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа работала всё время, а не останавливалась, когда считывает нажатие клавиши. Когда я вызываю Console.ReadKey(), программа ждёт, пока я нажму клавишу и не продолжает работать. В C++ есть _kbhit(), есть ли что-нибудь такое в C#?

Comment: `if (Console.KeyAvailable) keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);` ну или есть еще вот такой монстр https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201951/373567

Answer (score 1):

> Console.KeyAvailable - true if a key press is available; otherwise, false.

Если `KeyAvailable` возвращает `true`, вызывайте `Console.ReadKey` прочитать этот символ, иначе он останется во входном буфере и будет прочитан следующей командой ввода.

[Console.KeyAvailable Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=net-6.0#system-console-keyavailable)

Comment: Alex F, спасибо!

Comment: Лучше писать доп инфу не в комментарии, а отредактировать сам ответ. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Windows.cs#L268